# Spec has no expectation console error although expect is present

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the spec that has to expect still it says there are no expectations...

```
it('should click on yes button of technician and check save&continue functionality', () => {
    const saveAndContinue = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(saveContinueBtn)).nativeElement;
    saveAndContinue.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        const spy = spyOn(component,'isSaveAndContinueClicked').and.callThrough();
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
        expect(spy);
        component.isSaveAndContinueClicked();
        expect(component.isSaveAndContinueClicked).toHaveBeenCalled();
        const yesbutton = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#yesButton')).nativeElement;
        expect(yesbutton).toBeTruthy();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            spyOn(component, 'change').and.callThrough();
            spyOn(component, 'change2').and.callThrough();
            yesbutton.click();
            expect(component.change).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(component.change2).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
   });
});
```

It throws the error as spec testComponent should click on yes button of the technician and check save&continue functionality has no expectations...
Can you please suggest...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add your callback within an `async` or `fakeAsync` block or else all your code would run synchronously without encountering any `expects`.

This is because you are having assertions inside `fixture.whenStable().then(() => {....})` which runs asynchronously.

```
it('should click on yes button of technician and check save&continue 
  functionality', async(() => {
    const saveAndContinue = 
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(saveContinueBtn)).nativeElement;
    saveAndContinue.click();
    ........

}));
```

Comment: I had no luck with async or waitForAsync constructs with regards to this issue. fakeAsyc is the only one which saved my bacon.

Comment: For me fakeAsync also did not work,

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Amit's answer:

Since Angular 10 `async` can be replaced with `waitForAsync`. Using `async` also gives a deprecation warning. It is removed from v12 on.

Angular <= 11: `it("description", async(() => {}));`
Angular >= v12: `it("description", waitForAsync(() => {}));`

If you stick to those versions, you should be able to use `fakeAsync()` and `fixture.whenStable().then()` as expected.